# Is Orca wrongly breaking bonds? Why can it only optimize the molecule with COPT activated?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

I would like to ask for help in using Orca (v. 4.0.0) for conducting a simple optimization.

First I have this structure (primarily optimized using MMFF94s force field on Avogadro):

[image]

Thus I tried to conduct a simple optimization by using Orca and just as a test I used the following input:

```
! PAL8 PBE def2-SVP def2/JK RIJONX TightOpt TightSCF CPCM(DMSO) KeepDens NormalPrint Grid4 FinalGrid5
%method
    Z_MaxIter 150
end
%scf 
    MaxIter 150 
end

*xyz 0 1
C       4.026085     -1.212051      0.000031
C      -3.313454      0.000008     -0.000131
C       5.413748     -1.205853     -0.000365
C      -4.026091      1.212051     -0.000333
C       6.111884      0.000013     -0.000433
C      -5.413752      1.205847     -0.000315
C       5.413733      1.205871     -0.000018
C      -6.111885     -0.000021     -0.000102
C       4.026071      1.212051      0.000379
C      -5.413728     -1.205875      0.000032
C       3.313452     -0.000005      0.000350
C      -4.026066     -1.212050      0.000016
C       1.893686     -0.000008      0.000523
C       0.678508      0.000000      0.000397
C      -0.678520      0.000009      0.000187
C      -1.893672      0.000016     -0.000043
H       3.483003     -2.148319      0.000143
H       5.951276     -2.145874     -0.000768
H      -3.483012      2.148322     -0.000572
H       7.194627      0.000021     -0.001168
H      -5.951286      2.145866     -0.000334
H       5.951249      2.145899     -0.000149
H      -7.194627     -0.000032      0.000311
H       3.482975      2.148312      0.000762
H      -5.951240     -2.145905      0.000285
H      -3.482967     -2.148309      0.000048
```

Thus after running it, I saw that somehow Orca was "splitting" all bonds and getting this:

[image]

However, my job keeps going without detecting any problem and it just ends because hits the maximum allowed iterations.

I also tried to change the basis set, but without success. Also, I have played a lot with functionals, changed between LDA and GGA ones without success, semiempirical also have not shown any good result.

The only thing I could use to solve this problem was by setting COPT instead of OPT only, which changes Orca to cartesian coordinate (but was I already using cartesian coordinates?).

I just wonder why that is happening. Am I missing something? What is wrong with my input to cause Orca to "split" all atoms apart? And why Orca only can optimize this molecule with COPT activated?

Comment: Does this also happen if you remove `CPCM(DMSO)`?

Comment: About `copt`: Your input coordinates are transformed to some internal coordinates, which are then used for the optimization.  `copt` is about controlling these internal coordinates and thus independent of the input.

Comment: Hi Feodoran, yes. That also happens if I remove CPCM(DMSO). I also thought that could be the reason, but removing that did cause the same result.

Comment: If you inspect the output you can see a lot of "RMS(Cart) increases - taking linear step, building new B-matrix and trying again" messages that ends up with a cleat indication that something went wrong: "Not converged!" Since OP mentioned that switching to optimization in Cartesian coordinates solves the issue, it looks like a bug with optimization in internal coordinates.

Comment: @Feodoran, COPT in ORCA means that optimization is done directly in Cartesian coordinates without even constructing internal ones.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to be a bug with optimization in internal coordinates. As I already mentioned in comments, ORCA couldn't converge at geometry relaxation step when optimization is done in internal coordinates. Switching to optimization in Cartesian coordinates (`coordsys cartesian`) or old internal ones (`coordsys redundant_old`) in the `%geom` section of the input, or using the `! COPT` simple input as OP has done, solves the issue.

P.S. OP might report it as a bug at [ORCA forum](https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/viewforum.php?f=11) so that developers can take a closer look at this case.

Comment: In particular, the problem likely comes from the extended linear diyne linkage, possibly in combination with the planar capping benzenes. OP should definitely report this on the ORCA forum; the developers will want to know about the misbehavior.

Comment: I'm very pleased to know that. Thank you, Wildcat. I'll definitively report that on Orca forum. Thanks a lot for all of you guys who helped me with that. :D

Comment: https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3105